How to set Application Pool using msdeploy.exe cli when syncing IIS
I'm trying to write a script to install and sync certain applications on two IIS. Right now I'm using a .bat file in combination with PowerShell scripts to active this:
@echo OFF

rem set paramiters
set "webSiteName=SiteName"
set "siteRootDirectoryPath=C:\wwwroot"
set "ApiName=Api"
set "AppName=App"
set "psIntallScriptPath=C:\version\DeployApiAndAppToIIS.ps1"
set "psAppPoolScriptPath=C:\version\EnsureAppPool.ps1"
set "currentDirectory=%~dp0"

rem Call the PowerShell script with the parameters
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%psScriptPath%" -siteRootDirectory %siteRootDirectoryPath% -sourceDirectory %currentDirectory% -siteName %webSiteName% -appNames %ApiName%,%AppName%

rem Check the exit code of the PowerShell script

if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 101 (
        echo "Error %ERRORLEVEL%. update API and App"
        pause
        exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
    )
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 101 (
    echo "Could not find API/App zip files, they will not be installed"
    )
)
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    echo "Api and app for %webSiteName% updated" 
)

rem Sync IIS site
echo "Sync website %webSiteName% to Web2"
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:iisApp="%webSiteName%" -skip:Directory="\\Log$" -skip:Directory="\\%ApiName%" -dest:iisApp="%webSiteName%",computername=Web2

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo "Error %ERRORLEVEL%. Sync website %webSiteName% to Web2"
  pause
  exit %ERRORLEVEL%
)

rem Create a separate AppPool for the API
echo "Creating App Pool for API %ApiName%"
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:appPoolConfig="%webSiteName%%ApiName%" -dest:appPoolConfig="%webSiteName%%ApiName%",computername=Web2

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo "Error creating App Pool. Error %ERRORLEVEL%"
  pause
  exit %ERRORLEVEL%
)

rem Sync the API sub-application and assign the new App Pool
echo "Sync sub-application HiCoreApi and assign its app pool"
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:iisApp="%webSiteName%\%ApiName%" -skip:Directory="\\Log$" -dest:iisApp="%webSiteName%\%ApiName%",computername=Web2

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo "Error %ERRORLEVEL%. Sync website %webSiteName% to Web2"
  pause
  exit %ERRORLEVEL%
)

pause

goto :eof

the PowerShell first copies all folders on IIS-1, ensures settings, and creates app-pools for the two applications and the site itself, so three app-pools in total, and that all works great. Then the script syncs the site folder, syncs the app-pool and the app folder to IIS-2, but here is the issue. when syncing the apps use the same app-pool as the site, not the pool that is set in IIS-1 and copied to IIS-2.
I've tried gooleling and GPT, but i have no good answers. I know i can use PowerShell remotely, but I'm getting some authentication issues what I'm not having with msdeploy.exe so that is what I'd like to use.

You forgot to post the PowerShell script :)

Try to Run the command with -verbose, which can record the detailed steps of script execution. By specifying >msdeploysync-verbose.log, the results of the operation  will be listed in the log file and you can refer to this document.

@MathiasR.Jessen The powershell works as intenden and sets up all the proper applications and app-pools, it's the msdeploy.exe cli that is messing with me.

@alwashuang I'll take a look at that and see if it makes me any wiser, thanks for the tip

Hope you get useful information
